# Loosing userid in session when redirecting to page after inserting data from useing PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help on this problem I have, 2 PHP files, one is a form the other the PHP code to insert the data to the database. I am using a userID in a session to keep the data entered for the same user, my problem is after I submit the data to the database my page have to redirect to another page in the same session with the same userID but display the entered data in the table, but every time I submit it goes to the right page but without the userID, (437465375.php?userID=) if I put the user id in on the end (437465375.php?userID=33) it goes to the right page displaying the data enter in the table.

Here is the code for the form:

```
 <div class="posttext">
        <p><strong>PRIMARY INFORMATION TO BE FURNISHED BY A TAXPAYER AS REQUIRED BY SARS.</strong></p>
      <?php
       if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {

        echo " <form method='post' id='contatti' action='savetrip1.php?userID='" . $_GET['userID']."'>";
      ?>
         <div id="contactform">

           <?php
           echo "<p><h2><strong>Kilometre Recording</strong></h2></p>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'>Work Km Travelled  ( Total Km only not Speedomiter meter reading): </label> <input type='text' value='".$row['travelledKm']."' name='travelledKm' id='TravelledKm' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'>Date: YYYY-MM-DD </label><input type='text' value='".$row['LoggedDate']."' name='LoggedDate' id='LoggedDate' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<p><h2><strong>Business Travel Details</strong></h2></p>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'>From Where did you Travel: </label> <input type='text' value='".$row['fromk']."' name='fromk' id='fromk' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'>To Where did you Travel: </label> <input type='text' value='".$row['tok']."' name='tok' id='tok' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'>Reason: </label> <input type='text' value='".$row['Reason']."' name='Reason' id='Reason' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'> Fuel &amp; Oil Costs (R): </label> <input type='text' value='".$row['Fuel']."' name='Fuel' id='Fuel' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='commentfield'>";
           echo "<label for='author'>Repairs &amp; Maintenance Costs (R): </label> <input type='text' value='".$row['Repairs']."' name='Repairs' id='Repairs' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='contactbutton'>";
           echo "<input type='submit' class='contact-button' name='submit' id='invia'value='Save Trip' />"; 
           echo "<input type='reset' class='contact-button' name='clear' value='Clear Input' />";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "</form>";
           }
           ?>

      </div></div>
    </div>
```

And here is the php code for submiting the data to the mysql database:

```
    <?php
session_start('userID');


$host = "localhost";
$db = "database";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

$userID=$_SESSION['ID'];
$travelledKm=$_POST['travelledKm'];
$LoggedDate=$_POST['LoggedDate'];
$fromk=$_POST['fromk'];
$tok=$_POST['tok'];
$Reason=$_POST['Reason'];
$Fuel=$_POST['Fuel'];
$Repairs=$_POST['Repairs'];

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['submit']) == true) {

  $query = "INSERT INTO   `webimckr_lockbook`.`trip_log`(`userID`,`LoggedDate`,`travelledKm`,`fromk`,`tok`,`Reason`,`Fuel`,`Repairs`)VALUES ('$userID','$LoggedDate','$travelledKm','$fromk','$tok','$Reason','$Fuel','$Repairs')";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){

header("Location: 437465375.php?userID=".$_GET['userID']."");

}

else {
echo "ERROR";

} 

}

?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();

?>
```

I am very new to PHP and Mysql and learning on my own, please assist me with this so that I can understand it and for future use.

Comment: session_start() does not accept parameters

Comment: Where is the 'ID' value coming from? $userID=$_SESSION['ID'];

Comment: When I remove the useid in session_start it save the data but not the userid.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` was generating the phpsessionId which was unique for each browser, so u can check with your form post only

each refresh form will post your data what ever it is, so whether you can check post is empty or not

Comment: Array ( [username] => hannes [ID] => 33 [Loggedin] => 1 )

Answer (score 0):

This line does not look right to me:

```
$userID=$_SESSION['ID'];
```

you are using userID at the top then calling ID?? Use same name

Comment: I changed it to the same, still same results.

Comment: this line as well confusing:

     if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
you need to give the session variable a value some where in your code

Answer (score -1):

use `$_POST['userID']` instead of `$_GET['userID']`

Comment: userID is appended as GET parameter in the form action: `action='savetrip1.php?userID=`